If a function F is such that...
Suppose that $F(0) = 2 $ and $ F(1)=3$, and that $F(n+1)=2F(n)-F(n+2)$ for $ n ≠ 0$. Then what is $F(5)=?$
There was a correction in the question in the part where it says $n ≠ 0$  I found that after i saw they did put in $n=0$ in the solution attached with the question , but my question is what if $n≠0$ how do we approach this question then ? And if we cannot take $n≠0$ then why not ? Sorry pardon me if I attached the wrong tags or made a mistake in the question i am new here also being in high school I haven't studied the topics in much detail sorry.

This is hard to follow.  Maybe things would be clearer to you if you wrote the recursion in the more standard way, as $F(n+2)=2F(n)-F(n+1)$.  That's the usual idea...we use terms we know to get more terms.  Thus, taking $n=0$, we have $F(2)=2F(0)-F(1)=4-3=1$ and so on.  If you disallow the the recursion for $n=0$, then you need to tell us what $F(2)$ is.
